# How do I copy the last nonempty row values to another sheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

How do I copy the last nonempty row values to another sheet using VBA?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1651993

Comment: @Jeeva have you tried any of the answers you got ? any feedback ? thanks ?

Comment: @Jeeva really? you prefer the answer with `Select` all the time ?

Comment: Honestly i'm not care the way of code is designed as long it produce the result i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sub to do that.

```
    Sub CopyPaste()
        Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
          Rows(Selection.Row).Select
           Selection.Copy
           Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
          Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End Sub
```

Comment: Modify the sub as you need. This types of simple codes is available on internet. Do some google search, you will get tons of example.

Comment: realy ? you advice using `Select` , `Selection` and `Activate` and `ActiveSheet` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I just shown him a simplest way to do that. He seems beginner of VBA. Better answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As good practice, stay away from `Select` , `Selection`, `Activate` ,etc...

Instead, use referenced objects such as `Sheets` and `Range`s. Also take the time to learn how to use `With` statements, it will help you a lot to create shorter and clearer codes, and reduces the chances for bugs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()

Dim LastRow As Long

' copy last row from "Sheet1" >> modify to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in column A , skip empty cells in the middle
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' copy entire row with data from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2" first cell ("A1")
    .Rows(LastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are interested in "values" and not to uselessly copy cells outside used range, you could do like follows:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    With Sheets("SourceSheetName") '<--| reference "source" sheet (change "SourceSheetName" to your actual "source" sheet name)
        ' find last row with data in column A , skip empty cells in the middle
        With Range(.Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp), _
                   .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)) '<--| reference its range from its column A last not empty cell to this latter cell row last not empty cell
            Worksheets("TargetSheetName").Range("A1").Resize(, .Columns.count).Value = .Value '<--| paste values to "target" sheet starting from its cell A1 (change "TargetSheetName" to your actual "target" sheet name)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```